# Update con varios valores en SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

Como puedo hacer un update para que actualice varios valores mi query es

```
    UPDATE ACL_FAC SET ID_CARGA = 
(SELECT SEQUENCIA FROM ACL_FAC WHERE ID_CARGA IN (4005946,
4005947,
4005948,
4005949,
4005950)AND SEQUENCIA IN(680456522,
680482070,
680561046,
680561049,
680562329)
) 
WHERE ID_CARGA IN (4005946,
4005947,
4005948,
4005949,
4005950)AND SEQUENCIA IN(680456522,
680482070,
680561046,
680561049,
680562329)
```

lo que quiero hacer es actualizar el campo ID_CARGA colocando el valor que tiene SEQUENCIA pero esto es para varios valores, con un valor si se puede pero con varios valores como el ejemplo me genera error

> La subconsulta ha devuelto más de un valor, lo que no es correcto
>   cuando va a continuación de =, !=, <, <=, >, >= o cuando se utiliza
>   como expresión.

Comment: ¿No es algo como esto: `UPDATE ACL_FAC SET ID_CARGA = SEQUENCIA WHERE ID_CARGA IN (...) AND SEQUENCIA IN (..)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La opción directa es:

```
CREATE TABLE ACL_FAC (ID_CARGA INT, SEQUENCIA INT)
GO
INSERT INTO ACL_FAC(ID_CARGA, SEQUENCIA)
VALUES
(4005946,680456522),
(4000000,680000000),
(4005947,680482070),
(4005948,680561046),
(4005949,680561049),
(4000001,680000001),
(4005950,680562329);
GO
-- Codigo Ejemplo 1

UPDATE ACL_FAC
  SET 
      ID_CARGA = SEQUENCIA
       WHERE ID_CARGA IN(4005946, 4005947, 4005948, 4005949, 4005950)
AND SEQUENCIA IN(680456522, 680482070, 680561046, 680561049, 680562329);
```

Personalmente, prefiero antes de hacer la update saber cual va a ser el resultado y luego aplicarla. Para esto siempre utilizo una tabla de expresión común. Y con la salida de esta la cruzo con la tabla origen y veo lo que voy a hacer. Algo así como:

```
;WITH CTE
 AS (SELECT ID_CARGA
          , SEQUENCIA
     FROM 
          DBO.ACL_FAC
            WHERE ID_CARGA IN(4005946, 4005947, 4005948, 4005949, 4005950)
     AND SEQUENCIA IN(680456522, 680482070, 680561046, 680561049, 680562329))
 SELECT CASE
            WHEN CTE.ID_CARGA IS NULL
            THEN ACL_FAC.ID_CARGA
            ELSE CTE.SEQUENCIA
        END AS RESULTADO
 FROM 
      CTE
      RIGHT JOIN ACL_FAC ON CTE.ID_CARGA = ACL_FAC.ID_CARGA
                            AND CTE.SEQUENCIA = ACL_FAC.SEQUENCIA;
--)UPDATE CTE SET ID_CARGA = SEQUENCIA FROM CTE;
```

[image: Resultado obtenido]

Si el resultado obtenido es el esperado, entonces comento el código de la select y me quedo con la update. Si el conjunto es complejo, en vez de actualizar directamente el cte realizo una inner join contra la tabla a actualizar (en este caso no es necesario).

```
WITH CTE
 AS (SELECT ID_CARGA
          , SEQUENCIA
     FROM 
          DBO.ACL_FAC
            WHERE ID_CARGA IN(4005946, 4005947, 4005948, 4005949, 4005950)
     AND SEQUENCIA IN(680456522, 680482070, 680561046, 680561049, 680562329))
 --SELECT CASE
 --           WHEN CTE.ID_CARGA IS NULL
 --           THEN ACL_FAC.ID_CARGA
 --           ELSE CTE.SEQUENCIA
 --       END AS RESULTADO
 --FROM 
 --     CTE
 --     RIGHT JOIN ACL_FAC ON CTE.ID_CARGA = ACL_FAC.ID_CARGA
 --                           AND CTE.SEQUENCIA = ACL_FAC.SEQUENCIA;
UPDATE CTE SET ID_CARGA = SEQUENCIA FROM CTE;
-- otra opción valida es: UPDATE A SET ID_CARGA = SEQUENCIA FROM ACL_FAC A INNER JOIN CTE ON CTE.ID_CARGA = ACL_FAC.ID_CARGA
--                           AND CTE.SEQUENCIA = ACL_FAC.SEQUENCIA;
```

Si nunca has usado tablas de expresión común puede ayudarte leer esto:
[Cte](https://javifer2.wordpress.com/2018/12/18/with-cte-tablas-de-expresion-comun-1/)